# Android studio internationalization - IDE support for XLIFF standard

Tags: android-studio, internationalization, xliff

The industry standard file format for exchanging and sharing data for translation is the XLIFF type. Files of such format are used worldwide by translators, translating companies, developers, even simple users. An XLIFF file is actually a XML file that is created based on standard specification, and there are programs and applications capable of reading and building such files. You can find more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF)

My question and issue is does android studio support XLIFF files so i can easily deliver this to a linguistic company and then they can deliver it back to me for import ? apple's xcode 6 has this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the last version of Android Studio that I looked at the format of choice for string resources was XML (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). Any good localization vendor should be able to deal with XML files.

If you really need XLIFF you can use Okapi Rainbow (http://www.opentag.com/okapi/wiki/index.php?title=Rainbow) to convert Android XML to XLIFF. Note that the output from Rainbow is not really nice XLIFF because placeholders like `%d` are not wrapped in placeholder tags, but then the Android resource format is not really translator friendly either with its handling of apostrophes and quotation marks.